# How to get BarCodeView Bounds after setting it to autosize?

Tags: delphi, barcode, fastreport

I am creating a BarCodeView on Delphi at runtime and then adding it to a ReportPage on a TfrxReport.

the barcode displays just fine, but when I try to get its width I get 0 even if it is created and clearly longer than 0.

here is some code.

`Page:= Report.FindObject('Page1') as TfrxReportPage;`;

`BarCode:= TfrxBarCodeView.Create(Page)`;
`BarCode.Name:='Codigo'`;

```
BarCode.WideBarRatio:=2;
BarCode.Zoom:=1;
BarCode Font.Size:=6;
BarCode.ShowText:= True;
BarCode.BarType:= bcCodeEAN128;
```

`BarCode.Text:= 'Something123';`

`BarCode.AutoSize:=True;
       BarCode.Height:= 50;
       BarCode.Top:= 5;
       BarCode.Left:= 5;`

now, if I try to check the barcode view properties, I get 0 from it'd width property, even if I call the next:

`BarCode:=Report.FindComponent('Codigo') as TfrxBarCodeView`;

when showing a message like this:
`ShowMessage('code width: '+BarCode.Width.ToString)`;

I get 0 even if the BarCodeView displays fine in the report.

any ideas how to get those properties right with the autosize enabled and creating the barcode at runtime from Delphi?